# Is there a universal solution to prevent double-clicks in PHP/Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to sort out the best solution for double-clicks on the Web in general. Sometimes double-clicks lead to not just navigation, but they start some processing, which when ended are leading to collision, because those processes were not meant to be executed twice.

So basically there are several tricks we can do:

1. Prevent double-clicks on the browser-side. This is relatively easy,
   yet user can open couple tabs and do clicks in parallel which would
   still execute processes twice.
2. Do some kind of locks on the server
   side for those processes. I think that would be reliable enough,
   don't have anything against this solution except looks a bit
   overkill. In my case it just feels I will overwhelm the system with
   these locks.
3. Theoretical solution - bounce requests for the same url
   from the same IP address happening within a second on the web-server
   side. Googling something like that didn't help though, maybe there
   is an instrument for that I just don't know a proper name for.

All these solutions don't feel too good for me. Is there any common practice for this problem?

Comment: Most solutions are just intended to prevent accidental double clicks. I don't think it's common to try to prevent the user from intentionally opening multiple tabs.

Comment: Exactly. What I'd like to do is to protect my processes, so if a process is meant to be executed once, it should be executed once, no matter what. Trying to figure out best technique for that.

Comment: Since what you're trying to do is not common, there's not likely to be a common solution or best practice.

Comment: We do it on our checkout page by setting a cookie to the time of last purchase. If they try to make another purchase within 10 minutes, we prompt them. We also disable the submit button while the submission is processing, to prevent accidental double clicks.

Comment: The fact that it is not common is surprising for me. Why others are not having troubles like I do with these double-clicks?

Comment: Accidental double click protection is common. But protecting against them deliberately opening a second tab is not.

Comment: The term you're looking at for #3 is "rate limiting".

Comment: Your "theoretical solutiion" is rubbish - if this happens the client will junk any response to the first click and receive an error from the second. PRG helps a little - but usually the second click is a result of poor performance - and PRG just amplifies the problem when the delay is due to latency.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to protect against double clicks is to have DB-side protection. In some cases when UNIQUE KEY is not enough and CHECK CONSTRAINT is not available or is not enough either, triggers should be used. That brings to inability to have "corrupt" data, which was my primary problem. 
After improving DB side, I've improved application code to handle errors happening when triggers disallow insertion.
In addition to all that I've wrote JS for preventing double-clicks on important buttons and links which could previously lead to the data duplication.
All that seems to put issue to the ground.